# Why the autocomplete window in Sublime text 3 dosen't show when I edit HTML?

Tags: html, autocomplete, sublimetext3

I'm new to ST3 (just downloaded the latest build), and I have this issue: when I open new HTML file in ST3, the autocomplete only works when I hold ctrl+space (I use win 10), when I open css files, the autocomplete window pops when I type, without the need to hold any key. I want the same to be when I edit HTML (or any other file type, for that matter).
How do I do that? Why the HTML autocomplete dosen't show up?
I copied this line to the user settings, after an answer to similar question, and its not working:
"auto_complete_selector": "source, comment, text.plain, meta.tag, punctuation.definition.tag.begin, css",

I use the HTML sinppets and AllAutocomplete packages.

What can I do to solve this issue?

Thanks,
Yishai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `auto_complete_selector` only works for the `source` scope. You can add `text` (or `text.html` in your user settings.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work... the window only pops when I press "<" or when I hold ctrl + space, and not when I start to type